# Numpy, Numba nopythonmode compatible, way of avoiding for loop

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I have two a 2-D (N x N) and 3-D array (N x N x 3), respectively `xi` and `R`.
I have to perform the following computation:

```py
h = 0

for i in range(N):
    h += xi[i].dot(R[i].dot(R[i].T).dot(xi[i]))
```

This is included in a function decorated with numba (`@njit`). I'm trying to optimize the function, then I'd like to find a way to avoid the `for` loop. Is there a way to do it in plain numpy, with only [Numba supported functions](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/numpysupported.html#functions)?

P.S.: I know I could use `prange` and run the for loop in parallel to get some extra speed, but since `N` is quite small (~100) the function actually performs worse decorated with `@njit(parallel=True)`.

Comment: `for loops` in `njit` code don't hurt performance.

Comment: You will win more if you calculate (x*R)*(Rt*x). x*(R*Rt)*x is probably worst you could do.